# How to open app in android 13 , this is my personal webview app doesn't open in android 13

Tags: java, android

Please help me as my personal WebView app is not launching on Android 13. The installation is successful, but when I try to open it, the app opens and immediately closes.
I am encountering an issue with my personal WebView app on Android 13. While the application installs successfully, it fails to launch properly. Upon attempting to open the app, it immediately closes without any error messages or further indication of the problem. I am seeking assistance to resolve this matter.

To provide some context, my app is developed using Java and Android, and it has been functioning flawlessly on Android versions 6 through 12. However, this issue arises exclusively on Android 13

Comment: Is the app crashing? Can you see the stacktrace in the Logcat?

Comment: yes i will check , app not crash